# Make the "Add New Post" one column for all users

Tags: themes

I have looked everywhere and there's been a few attempts to do this in my themes function.php file but no luck.

What I'm after is that to make it easier for my Contributors, that the add new post is in one column, easier for them to do it step by step.

I know I can change it in the screen options but I would like it by default so then they have it all done for them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one, there is a filter called `meta-box-order_{$page}` where page is the name of the post type so for post you can use:

```
add_filter('meta-box-order_post','one_column_for_all');

 function one_column_for_all($result, $option, $user){
    $result['normal'] = 'postexcerpt,formatdiv,submitdiv,trackbacksdiv,tagsdiv-post_tag,categorydiv,postimagediv,postcustom,commentstatusdiv,slugdiv,authordiv';
    $result['side'] = '';
    $result['advanced'] = '';
    result $result;
 }
```

this is untested!!! but should work.

Comment: I tried putting that into my functions.php Bainternet but no luck. I have tried a few snippets of code now but nothing seams to actually work this issue. Thanks,
Art

Comment: How does this affect the screen options panel? What if a user then switches to two-column, will all their settings be lost upon a page refresh?

Comment: Yes this overwrites the user settings when refreshed